# vsftpd service with tls enabled exit code 2

Tags: centos, ftp, puppet, tls, centos7

I am trying to set up TLS for VSFTPD on CentOS7. Whenever I try to start the service it fails with exit code 2 and no other information.

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=YES
ftpd_banner=Inari FTP Server
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=NO
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
hide_ids=NO
setproctitle_enable=NO
text_userdb_names=NO
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
rsa_cert_file=/home/yamiko/ssl/foo.crt
rsa_private_key=/home/yamiko/ssl/foo.key
```

Comment: How is this related to puppet?

Comment: I am managing it with puppet

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated which puppet module your using along with your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I commented out the `#listen_ipv6=YES` line in */etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf* and vsftp started.
Don't forget to run `systemctl enable vsftpd.service` so it will start automatically after reboot. `systemctl status vsftpd.service` and check that it says "enabled".

Comment: The timestamps on this website seem 3 years off. Just an observation. I may not have looked at this post if I was looking for answers to a recent issue, which this is.